# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'X\node_modules\ng-zorro-antd\src\ng-zorro-antd.less'

Tags: javascript, angular

i using angular 6.0.1 . when i need to use `ng-zorro-antd` it show me this error :

> > ERROR in multi ../node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/src/ng-zorro-antd.less ./src/styles.css
> >             Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'E:\AngularTraning\node_modules\ng-zorro-antd\src\ng-zorro-antd.less' in 'E:\AngularTraning\Authorize'

i install `ng-zorro-antd` with this command : `npm install ng-zorro-antd --save`

and import this :

```
   BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
HttpClientModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
NgZorroAntdModule.forRoot()
```

add `ng-zorro-antd.less` in `angular.json` :

```
"styles": [
          "../node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/src/ng-zorro-antd.less",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
```

whats the problem ? how can solve that ?

Comment: I think, you mention two time node_modules in styles.

Comment: @baj9032 i fix that but still show me that problem

Comment: check ng-zorro-antd.less file exists or not in respective directory.

Comment: @baj9032 yes it exist

Comment: Just try npm install ng-zorro-antd@next --save.

Comment: @baj9032 i use this code but still show me that error

Comment: For more detail you just place new issue on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Your path seems wrong. Replace `..` with `./`

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Firstly, is your Angular project running on SASS/SCSS OR LESS ? You cant have both preprocessors in the same project. Chances are you are having the Sassy CSS (SCSS) preprocessor with your Angular project.

**SOLUTION 1: Replace it with the .min.css**

```
"./node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.min.css"
```

**SOLUTION 2: Replace the line with {"input": }**

If this has to work,  you have to make sure your project is using LESS preprocessor and NOT SCSS

```
{"input": "../node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/src/ng-zorro-antd.less"}
```